# How do I handle Chrome Autofill using Selenium Python?

Tags: selenium-webdriver, python

I encountered an issue using the chrome autofill option. There is any way to handle the options list? (please see the image)

What I've done:

1. Load my Chrome Profile
2. Launch Chrome with my loaded profile
3. Navigate to the checkout page(a form with an address in general)
4. Click on First Name input - to trigger the autofill list

The problem is that I cannot select any of those options(see picture).
So far I tried sending keys(ARROW_DOWN|DOWN, ARROW_UP|UP) + ENTER|RETURN -  with and without focus on the input field. I tried to refresh the page before doing all this as well. No positive result.

In the console, there is nothing generated and you cannot inspect the list generated by Chrome Autofill. I tried to see maybe an event is triggered or something else, but no luck.

I want a solution(if possible) that can offer a sort of logic because I'm planning to have multiple addresses, so I don't want to select just a random address.

[image]